# Search by relevance SQL

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x, relevance

I would love to search strings from database but i want it to order by relevance

I have picked up this example and is believed to work just fine.

**Before search**

> 1. The quick brown dog jumped fox-like.
> 2. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
> 3. The quick fox jumped over the Sears Tower.

**After search**

> 2. The **quick** **brown** **fox** jumped over the **lazy** **dog**.
> 3. The **quick** **brown** **dog** jumped **fox**-like.
> 4. The **quick** **fox** jumped over the Sears Tower.

**Code used**

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `description` LIKE 'quick'
AND (
  `description` LIKE 'brown'
  OR `description` LIKE 'fox'
  OR `description` LIKE 'lazy'
  OR `description` LIKE 'dog'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
ORDER BY (
  (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'brown'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'fox'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'lazy'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  ) + (
    CASE WHEN `description` LIKE 'dog'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
  )
) DESC
```

My question is. When users do the search, the search terms are dynamic. How do i add a for each in between the order by For the search to work.

What i have tried but still i know it wont work. First I don't know how to implode the + sign

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY ";

foreach ($words as $word) {
        $sql .= " ( CASE WHEN `pd.name` LIKE  '%".$word."%'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) + "; 
       }
$sql .= " ASC";
```

This is an Opencart Search Query example.

The code below works but how do i make it dynamic

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY 
( CASE WHEN pd.name like '%".$word1."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ 
( CASE WHEN pd.name like '%".$word2."%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC";
```

Comment: Not sure about the specifics of OpenCart - but it might be worth looking at a [Natural Language Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html); that will require a `FULLTEXT` index though which may, or may not, be in place already. You *might* also be able to offload it onto something like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: Is [Fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) an option?

Comment: @kerbholz Yes .Any findings i appreciate.

Comment: @CD001 The solution doesn't have to be in relation to opencart. If i get a general SQL answer it will work for me

Comment: @kerbholz correction. Fulltext search is not an option. the words are already split

Comment: This one works but how do i make it dynamic `$sql .= " ORDER BY ( CASE WHEN pd.name like  '%".$word1."%'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) + ( CASE WHEN pd.name like  '%".$word2."%'
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) DESC";`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about the specifics of the OpenCart database to give a definitive answer; you could still use a `FULLTEXT` search by just gluing your search terms back together with `implode()` ... but if the table collation is case sensitive you may hit problems.